# Verifying that there is visual feedback when response to any action in an app takes more than 3 seconds

Tags: android, response, user-feedback

I was working on an Android app in which I wanted to insert a specific feedback response from user. Whenever an app action is not responding for more than 3 seconds than I wanted a visual feedback which may include screenshot of app at that particular instance. I was wondering is there any way I can accomplish this task using any tools or 3rd party application integration?

Comment: As a good practice all time consuming actions shall be performed on non UI thread. This leaves your UI thread responsive and you can give feedback to the user as and when needed. Showing a screenshot not a good idea as the user will still not be able to interact with it.

Comment: Thank you but this is the specific requirement for app hence can't help any way to achieve same :*(